# Does Rashba-type SOC split bulk bands?

Tags: condensed-matter

The Rashba-type SOC is usually caused by structure inversion asymmetry(SIA).  I can understand that the Rashba-type SOC splits surface states because interfaces including surfaces have SIA. But I am not sure that Rashba-type SOC splits bulk bands if there is lack of inversion symmetry in the bulk. Although I know Dresselhaus-type SOC is caused in this case, I am also wondering whether both Rashba-tyape SOC and Dresselhaus-type SOC occur or not.

Comment: For instance, in HfO$_2$ and (as I remember) in BaInO$_3$ both SOC exist (Dresselhaus & Rashba). For bulk bands splitting, could you please chek the following paper https://www.pnas.org/content/111/19/6900 .

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov: Thank you. I'll check the paper.

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov: I have checked the paper. The inversion symmetry-breaking comes from the bulk polarization, not from the surface. My understanding is this causes not surface states splitting but bulk bands splitting. Is this correct?